# Compare x,y,z coordinates in two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

Im super fresh in programming so i will ask something very basic probably. I have a file which consists of x,y,z coordinates and a fourth value, and a second file with x,y,z values. The coordinates of the second file are contained randomly in the first file. What i wanted to do is to search the first file for the exact coordinates of the second file, and if they are the same, modify the fourth value of the first file.

I have written something that works, but it is extremely time consuming (it takes three hours..). The first file is about 300K lines and 4 columns, while the second one around 100K and three columns.

Below the code i wrote:

```
import numpy as np
with open('first file.txt', 'r') as t1:
    l1=[]
    for line in t1:
        split = line.split()
        l1.append((float(split[0]),float(split[1]),float(split[2]),float(split[3])))
l3=np.asarray(l1)

with open('second file.txt', 'r') as t2:
    l2=[]
    for line in t2:
        split = line.split()
        l2.append((float(split[0]),float(split[1]),float(split[2])))


with open('result file.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    for i in l3:        
        for j in l2:            

            if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2]:


                i[3]+=970000000

                #outFile.write(i)
                #print(i[3])
np.savetxt("result file.txt",l3,fmt='%7.4f'*3+'%10.3f')
```

If you have any tip to make this process faster please let me know!

Comment: If you don't mind an additional library, try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to read the data into a `DataFrame` and then make the x, y and z coordinates an index. This will make the lookup much faster. Alternatively, you could consider a dictionary instead of an array. Or else use a 3D np.array if your x, y and z are regular or a sparse array if they're not. I think pandas will be the easiest for you. The idea behind all of them is to take your nested loop, O(n^2) down to a single loop, O(n) which should be incomparably faster.

Comment: You don't need to convert all values to floats if the only thing you're doing is comparing. Not sure if that speeds everything up though.

Comment: Also, maybe you can put the data from file 2 in a simple list and instead of the second for loop do: if value1 in list_file2:
Then instead of 300K*100K iterations, you only have 300K iterations. A considerable amount less.

Comment: @Landcross If you do `if value in list_file2` you may have fewer loops, but the same number of comparisons. Use a `set` or `dict` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `set` or `dict` for storing the coordinates from the files. This way, you can do a O(1) lookup instead of having to compare each pair or cordinates from both files. Thus, you have just `300k + 100k` iterations, instead of `300k x 100k`. Something like this (not tested):

```
coords_first = {}
with open('first file.txt', 'r') as t1:
    for line in t1:
        *pts, val = map(float, line.split())
        coords[pts] = val

coords_second = set()
with open('second file.txt', 'r') as t2:
    for line in t2:
        pts = tuple(map(float, line.split()))
        coords_second.add(pts)

with open('result file.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    for pts in coords_first:
        if pts in coords_second:
            new_val = coords_first[pts] + 970000000
            # write points and new value to file
```

Here, `coords_first` is mapping the coordinates from the first file to the values, i.e. `{(x1,y1,z1): v1, (x2,y2,z2): v2, ...}`. `coords_second` is just the set of coordinates from the second file. You could also do without it and write the result file directly while iterating the second file, though.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Worked like a charm! It now takes only 3 seconds!!